# Return non null Interface object from GenericClass<T> or better programming pattern?

Tags: c#, wcf, design-patterns, interface

I have a Generic class as below.

```
Subscriber<T> where T : class
{
    public T callback {get; set;} 
    public USER User {get; set;}
}
```

T is really an interface for the callback being passed in and around. However as you know when I go to use this Null Reference Exception is thrown. So I go and search stack'O to create an instance of interface T , as you know I can't create an instance of an interface (duh) but I thought maybe there was a way around this. I am using WCF and would like to store the callback object but do it generically as the Subscriber method could be used for other callback contracts. Should I store as object and on the get cast to type T ?

```
private object _callback;
public object Callback
get
{
    return (T)_callback;
}
set
{
    _callback = value;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I create this object in my Client and I pass this into my Service Subscribe method. The callback cannot be set in the client because I do not have a callback object there (at least that I know of). So in my Subscribe method of the Service I have `Subscriber.Callback = OperationContext.Current;`
Perhaps my design pattern for storing this value in the class is wrong - how to do it ?

**EDIT:** Code Posted per Daniels Request. Comments in code indicate where issues reside. In the Subscribe method of the WCFServer - I get NRE. of course.
In the Form where the user is created - I can not set the Callback to a new one as it is not created yet and is only an interface. How do I create the User Class in my Client Form, with the callback parameter so it can be used in my Server to store the callback. Should I just declare it as object and cast to T? Or is my logic here wrong - any help is appreciated!

**CLIENT FORM:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
Form1()
{
this.ServiceSubscriber = new WCF.Subscriber<WCF.Interfaces.IDataCallback>();
// Problem occurs that I cant set the callback here. 
// this.ServiceSubscriber.Callback 
}
public void WCFClientLogin(WCF.Subscriber<WCF.Interfaces.IDataCallback> subscriber)
{
    if (WCFClient == null)
    {
        WCFClient = new WCF.ClientProxy();
    }
    WCFClient.StartClient(subscriber);
}
}
```

**INTERFACE :**

```
interface IDataCallBack
{
 [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
 void Subscribe(WCF.Subscriber<WCF.Interfaces.IDataCallback> subscriber);
}
```

**SUBSCRIBER CLASS :**

```
public class Subscriber<T> : ISubscriber<T> where T : class
{
 public T Callback {get; set;}
 public Guid UniqueIdentifier {get; set;}
 public Subscriber(T callback)
 {
   this.UniqueIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid();
   this.Callback = callback;
 }
}
```

**WCF SERVICE :**

```
public void Subscribe(Subscriber<IDataCallback> registrant)
{
    lock (_syncSubscribe)
    {
        try
        {
            IDataCallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IDataCallback>();
                        // RegisteredUser is Dictionary<Guid, IDataCallback>
// I can't set it here either because I get null reference exception.
            RegisteredUser[registrant.UniqueIdentifier].Callback = callback;
        }
        catch(Exception e) // TODO: More Explicit Catch
        {
           OnServerException(e);

        }               
    }           
}
```

Comment: If you don't set `callback` ever, it doesn't matter if it's an `object` or `T`, you'll still get a NRE. Why are you not accepting an instance of `T` in your constructor, for example?

Comment: That won't help at all.  Your question is extremely unclear.

Comment: @yuval T is an interface; so when I store in the dictionary directly as simply <guid,IMyCallback> I can do this and have access to it.  When I encapsulate IMyCallback in the Subscriber Class I can't set it as I get NRE, 
I pass this Subscriber object into the service from the client - it is not set at the client as the callback is not available at that point. So in my Service in the subscribe method I want to set the callback. Subscriber.Callback = (IMyCallBack)context;

Comment: @Stix: Please provide a short but complete sample demonstrating your problem. It's not clear from your description.

Comment: _"I can't create an instance of an interface (duh) but I thought maybe there was a way around this"_ -- no, there is no way around this. You cannot deserialize interfaces, unless they are "special" with known default implementations (e.g. `IList<T>`), and even then whether it will work will depend on your exact context. The receiving end needs to know the type used to implement the interface, otherwise it has no way to ensure the deserialized object will behave the same as the serialized object. Just fix your contract so it uses a concrete type instead of an interface.

Comment: Please post as answer ,so I can accept it, I would post make the contract type concrete as the answer but I do not think that is fair to you. @Peter Duniho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"I can't create an instance of an interface (duh) but I thought maybe there was a way around this"* — no, there is no way around this. You cannot deserialize interfaces, unless they are "special" with known default implementations (e.g. `IList<T>`), and even then whether it will work will depend on your exact context.

The receiving end needs to know the type used to implement the interface, otherwise it has no way to ensure the deserialized object will behave the same as the serialized object. Just fix your contract so it uses a concrete type instead of an interface.